# permission deny

Tags: errors, windows

This is what I write:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt] {article}
\usepackage {amsmath}
\usepackage {mathptmx}
\usepackage[12pt] {moresize}
\begin{document}

\section{2.7 Derivatives}

The \emph{derivative of a function f at a number a}
\[
f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a + h) - f(a)}{h} 
\]
\\* if we write x = a + h, then h = x - a
\\*and h approaches 0 if and only if x approaches a

\[
f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} 
\]

\section{2.8 Derivative as a Function}

\\*{\ssmall p154 The tangent at A, B is horizontal, so the deriavative is 0 and the graph o f f' cross the x-axis at the poins at A', B'}
\\* if f'(a) exists
\\* f is differentiable at a, it's differentiable on at every number in the interval}

\end {document}
```

but it comes out like this

```
\texify.exe: Permission denied: calculus 2.7.log
texify.exe: Data: calculus 2.7.log
```

did I write anything wrong?

Comment: Looks more like an execution issue rather than the actual contents. What happens when you try to run latex on a very minimal file? Like, \documentclass{article}\begin{document} Hello \end{document}

Comment: It prompt out told me that I have to install a package or something

Comment: What exactly is the message?

Comment: It told me that the package is missing so that I have to download the package. After I download the package, I can't run it anymore. I'm using TExwork

Answer (score 10):

[ **Just to answer the unanswered, converting comments into an answer** ]

This kind of problems can be resolved removing spaces from filenames.

Rename your file from `calculus 2.7.tex` to `calculus2.7.tex` and you will have no problems.

In fact, although recent versions of TeX compilers "tolerate" them, it is always a good practice not to have spaces in filenames.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled across this error message in TeXworks.
By the look of it, it happens, when the compiler runs into an error and followed by that, can't exit the `pdflatex`-process properly.
So it has not the permission to execute an other instance of `pdflatex`.

In TexMaker it simply says: 'Can't start the process.'

System: Win7 32bit

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem while trying to add the `adjustbox` package.

To get it to run again, I ended the pdflatex program from Task Manager (running as a background program), deleted all the support files for the LaTeX document (you can't do this without ending pdflatex), then reopened the main document.

I just deleted the new code and the package, so it wouldn't happen again.  I don't know how to actually work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.
I tried terminating the processes "winedit" and "pdflatex" from the Task Manager and restarted winedit.
Compiled the .tex file again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting the same message, maybe with other (built) files (.aux, .pdf, etc), check if you didn't accidentally drag & drop a file into the editor. Turns out I did, and TexMaker added a `\includegraphics[scale=1]{build/document.pdf}` line in the middle of the document. The file was being made and requested to read the same time, and this caused the error.

(Sorry if it's spam, but maybe helps someone hopelessly searching for the error.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't think this is the case of the OP, because the problem was with the log file.

Comment: Actually, that observation is worth keeping. Sometimes the inadvertent mistakes, unrelated to code, are hard to hunt down.